# ECM questions on 1986 G30

Tags: chevrolet, electronic-control-module

Dumb question perhaps.....but I've gotten different answers.  Does my 1986 G30 motorhome have an ECM....if so where is it located.  Everything I've read says that a low idle problem cannot be adjusted on the carb because it's the ECM that controls that.  I am lost....

Comment: I don't know if you can adjust the idle or not, but it has a carburetor, so I'm doubting it has an ECM.

Comment: Deleting previous questions also means deleting the effort people made to help you. Your new idle question is fine and keeping the previous question would have been fine...

Comment: And then I can see it can also have an O2 sensor, so it could very well have an ECM ... and looking further, [it *can* have an ECM](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/chevrolet,1986,g30,5.7l+350cid+v8,1047945,electrical,engine+control+module+(ecm+computer),2896). They are usually located in the passenger's side, behind the kick panel.